# Vue.js scoped css not working in single file component

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, sfc

I tried to set up a single file component. But the specified css (also scoped css) are ignored and not rendered.

I tried it with a simple component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>A Headline</h1>
    <p>A test example</p>
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Component is rendered fine, except that the css style is not applied.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are your using `h1` class which you specified in the style? If it is tag then you need to remove the dot.

Comment: yes, it was a mistake in this post. originally i used it without the dot

Comment: Can you paster your webpack config please? I am having a similar issue...

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: *This answer was a solution to the question as originally posted. It no longer applies in light of the revised code example. I'll update this again when I have an answer to the question as it stands.*

---

You are applying the style to the class `.h1` but no element has this class.  It seems likely you intended to apply the style to `h1` elements, so remove the `.` from the name of your style definition:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>A Headline</h1>
    <p>A test example</p>
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: You are right. But it was only is misstake by typing here. I used h1 in my code, but also several other selectors to test. No css code will apply

Comment: Ah, I'd suggest  asking a new question with the correct code sample and explanantion.  Or edit this question, but in a way that preserves the original situation so that answers don't become confusing. In either case I'll try to see what else may be the trouble.

Comment: just fixed the post